# transferring the remained array objects from one component to the other during mapping of an array

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, components, jsx

i have an array of objects in react i want to map these object on a first component in react but i fixed the height of first component to 300px when the array size complete i want to shift the remain objects to the second component and map the remained objects in the second component please help.

```js
let arrayOfObjects = [{title: "karim"}, {title:"fawad"},{title: "karim"}, {title:"fawad"},{title: "karim"}, {title:"fawad"},{title: "karim"}, {title:"fawad"}];

let firstComponent = <div height="300px">
arrayOfObjects.map(e)=><div height="100px">{e.title}</div>
</div>;

let secountComponent = <div height="300px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just do the math before you use map to calculate the number of objects you want to select from the array, and then use slice? 
So instead of

```
arrayOfObjects.map(e)=><div height="100px">{e.title}</div>
```

Do this

```
arrayOfObjects.slice(0,3).map(e)=><div height="100px">{e.title}</div>
```

and then use slice again to put the remaining data in a separate component.

```
arrayOfObjects.slice(3).map(e)=><div height="100px">{e.title}</div>
```

You could even calculate the values for slice programmatically, and replace the value 3 with the value of the first component height, divided by the height of each title

By the way, I think you need to put the map function into curly brackets {} in order for the JSX to render correctly, otherwise it will just print the text of your function.

Comment: how to calculate dynamically and solve, if it is possible please give an example, and kindly read my first comment, thanks liam

Answer (score 0):

You can slice an array and place each sublist in 
separate component

--Edit

As items might have different height and a different approach is needed.

That means items should be grouped into chunks as long as their sum height doesn't exceed specified value.

**Example**

```js
let arrayOfObjects = [{
  title: "karim"
}, {
  title: "fawad"
}, {
  title: "karim"
}, {
  title: "fawad"
}, {
  title: "karim"
}, {
  title: "fawad"
}, {
  title: "karim"
}, {
  title: "fawad"
}];

const random = (from, to) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from) + from);

const randomStyle = () => {
  
  return {
    height: random(70, 130),
    background: `rgb(${random(0, 255)}, ${random(0, 255)}, ${random(0, 255)})`
  }
}

arrayOfObjects = arrayOfObjects.map(pr => ({...pr, style: randomStyle()}));

const FixedComponent = ({height, items}) => {
  const computedHeight = `${height}px`;

  return <div className="fixed" style={{height: computedHeight}}>
   {items.map(({title, style}, id) => <div className="item" key={id} style={style}>{title}</div>)}
   </div>
}

const App = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setItems(arrayOfObjects);
  },[]);

  const renderComponents = function*() {
    
    let bucket = [];
    let sumOfHeights = 0;
    const maxHeight = 300;
    let id = 1;
    
    for(let item of items) {
      
      const height = item.style.height;
      
      if(maxHeight > sumOfHeights + height) {
        bucket = [...bucket, item];
        sumOfHeights = sumOfHeights + height;
        continue;
      }
      
      const items = [...bucket];
      yield (<FixedComponent key={id} height={maxHeight} items={items}></FixedComponent>);
      bucket = [];
      id = id + 1;
      sumOfHeights = 0;
    }
    
    id = id + 1;
    
    yield (<FixedComponent key={id} height={maxHeight} items={bucket}></FixedComponent>);
  }

  return <div>
    {[...renderComponents()]}
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.fixed {
  padding: .5rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.8.7/polyfill.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: the height of the objects inside of array is different in some scenario and also the length of the array also dynamic, in this case how auto fix the items inside the fixed height component and map the remained section on next component, and if the next component size full we have to generate the third component automatically like Microsoft word(when you typing ms word automatically generate the new paper for you)

Comment: assuming we are mapping a dynamic array of objects with vary height inside the ms word paper when the first paper filled the ms word generate for us a new paper and shift our content, and in this case shift the objects in to secound paper,, please help me in this case i really need thanks

Comment: Updated answer. The code got quite complex and one assumption is we still know the heights of each item somehow.

Comment: in this solution when i want to print some objects auto hide and do not show for example when i add 7 objects it only show six and or 5 items